# How to create new Google Sheets in Swift 4 using Sheets API v4

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I can't figure out how to create a new Google sheets in Swift 4 using the Sheets API. I would also like the use the same Google sheets later on in my code and so I would need it to return a value for the spreadsheet ID. This is what I have so far.

```
func createNewSheet() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {
        (data, response, error) in
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    }
    task.resume()
    print (task)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an [Add a Sheet guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#add_a_sheet) from the docs:

> The following spreadsheets.batchUpdate request adds a sheet to a
>   spreadsheet, while also setting the title, size, and tab color. This
>   request returns an AddSheetResponse, consisting of an object with the
>   created sheet's properties (such as its sheetId).
>
> The request protocol is shown below. The Updating Spreadsheets guide
>   shows how to implement a batch update in different languages using the
>   Google API client libraries.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addSheet": {
        "properties": {
          "title": "Deposits",
          "gridProperties": {
            "rowCount": 20,
            "columnCount": 12
          },
          "tabColor": {
            "red": 1.0,
            "green": 0.3,
            "blue": 0.4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```